# Real time Alternative to polling in ruby on rails (Jruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, real-time

I have a long running operation that I activate by placing a message on a ruby resque queue.  The endpoint does the work which might take many minutes.

I was going to periodically poll the database every few second but I think the world has moved on from polling.  Is there a better way using ruby on rails to get the results as a push, perhaps using something like web sockets or comet?

Can anyone suggest anything to start my research?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye

Comment: Websockets are the obvious answer... But while you are at it, you could give the users more info than just "done/not done". https://github.com/idris/resque-progress with resque progress you can give completeness

Comment: I have some code that spiders round a website and screen scrapes results from each web page.  I want to push the results back to the front end as they are found.  The spider can take a few minutes to complete.

Answer (score 3):

[Websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) is the thing to research, and [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) is a good way to get started with it.

Answer (score 1):

em-websocket..or websocket-rails